# NSTimer Doesnt Stop

Tags: nstimer, restart

I use an NSTimer (Caused by an Old Question, Thank you again, guys! :-) ) to Refresh my Buttons in an Interval. But I can't Stop it!

I am Using iOS 4.3 as my Min Version.

invalidate doesn't work. And release isn't available for me.

Source:

```
int i = 0;
NSTimer *t;
bool running = false;

- (void)UpdateButton
{
     if(!running)
{
NSTimer *t = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1
                                              target: self
                                            selector:@selector(onTick:)
                                            userInfo: nil
                                             repeats:YES];

    running = true;

}
else
{
    bool value = t.isValid;
    [t invalidate];
    t = NULL;
    t = nil;
}
}


-(void)onTick:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    UIView *view = viewButtons;

for(UIButton *btnItem in view.subviews)
{
    NSString *strValue = [@(i) stringValue];
    btnItem.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [btnItem setTitle: strValue forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
}
```

It works fine, but it doesn't Stop!!!

How can I Stop and Start the NSTimer?

Best Regards

Comment: Why the archaic 4.3? 5.0 is the lowest you should get (for ARC), but a 7.0 target is desirable nowadays. And.. only use `nil` for objects.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got it.

I Have to Sorround it with an dispatch asnyc:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
if (t.isValid)
    {
......
```